# Copy specific column (4) from each table and paste it to the another document in table in column 4 in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, cpu-word

I am using below code to copy to a column 4 from Source document for all to Column 4 in target document column looping all table of source document table.

As both document has the same table but Source A document has data in column 4 and Source B document didn't have any data in it.

So, trying to copy a data from source A to source B but getting

"Command not available" when I run below code.

I searched for the solution I found that I am using clipboard but instead of clipboard I need to use Range function.

Code:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, t As Long
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select the source file"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    Set DocSrc = Documents.Open(.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  Else
    MsgBox "No source file selected. Exiting", vbExclamation
  End If
End With
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select the target file"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  Else
    MsgBox "No target file selected. Exiting", vbExclamation
    DocSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
  End If
End With
With DocSrc

For t = 4 To DocSrc.Tables.Count

DocSrc.Tables(t).Columns(4).Select
Selection.Copy

With DocTgt

DocTgt.Tables(t).Columns(4).Select
Selection.Paste


End With

Next
End With
End Sub
```

As i am not much aware of range function so, need a hint for the same.

Comment: Columns don’t have a range. This is one of the rare cases where you have to use Selection and the clipboard. If your documents contain a lot of tables then you will inevitably run into timing issues and will need to allow the OS to catch up. Using `DoEvents` in your code can help.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you for the suggestion i think it was due to speed of the macros I have used `Sleep` function and give a 2 second of sleep and then it worked correctly as macros get slow but it working perfectly. Thank you